# Regression for a data frame of bicycle services

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I have a data frame of bicycle services from Juanary 2020, that look like this

| Travel_Id | User_Id | Gender | Start_time | End_time | Origen_Id | Destiny_Id | Age | Duration | Day | Lat_Ori | Lon_Ori | Lat_Des | Lon_Des |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14420217 | 451617 | Male | 2020-01-01 06:02:20 | 2020-01-01 06:05:38 | 52 | 268 | 28 | 3.3000000 | Wednesday | 20.67575 | -103.3546 | 20.67529 | -103.3466 |
| 14420218 | 324211 | Male | 2020-01-01 06:02:22 | 2020-01-01 06:07:32 | 254 | 180 | 35 | 5.1666667 | Wednesday | 20.67848 | -103.3651 | 20.68803 | -103.3627 |
| 14420219 | 611633 | Male | 2020-01-01 06:03:01 | 2020-01-01 06:21:43 | 258 | 278 | 39 | 18.7000000 | Wednesday | 20.66318 | -103.3294 | 20.66265 | -103.3655 |

The project consists in doing visualization analysis but my teacher wants to add a little of linear regression. The mechanism of the service is that you can have unlimited trips, but each one of them can't have a duration greater than 30 minutes, in case of exceeding a "fine" is charged.

I wanted to predict which type of user are the ones that exceed the 30 minutes limits, so in R I was doing something like this

```
   rout_excced <- subset(jan2020, Duration > 30)
   dur <- lm(formula = Duration ~ Age+Gender+Day, data =route_exceed)
   summary(dur)
```

which gives this information

```
  lm(formula = Duracion ~ Edad + Genero + dia, data = rutas_excede)

  Residuals:
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
   -75.1   -31.9   -22.0   -10.6 24679.6 

  Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
  (Intercept)    49.6781    15.5184   3.201  0.00138 **
  Age            -0.1297     0.3987  -0.325  0.74500   
  GenderFemale    14.1675     9.5667   1.481  0.13868   
  DayThursday     8.4631    14.0653   0.602  0.54739   
  DayMonday      44.3010    14.5982   3.035  0.00242 **
  DayTuesday     13.0043    14.8353   0.877  0.38075   
  DayWednesday   11.1022    14.3045   0.776  0.43770   
  DaySaturday    30.9561    16.7695   1.846  0.06494 . 
  DayFriday      12.9115    13.6455   0.946  0.34408   

  Residual standard error: 336.4 on 6367 degrees of freedom
  Multiple R-squared:  0.001997,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.0007427 
  F-statistic: 1.592 on 8 and 6367 DF,  p-value: 0.1214
```

From this we only have that the day Monday have relationship to the duration of the trips, but nothing more. Am I doing this right? Should I make another linear regression? why the summary shows six days and one gender but does not day Sunday?

Comment: Day=Sunday and Gender=Male is the base case.  See this question for an explanation of multiple linear regression with factor variables. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547577/multiple-regression-r-output-how-to-interpret-the-intercept/547588#547588

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't model only the users that exceed 30 minutes. What you are modelling is how duration varies with your predictor variables *for only that group*. Instead, you could try modelling the problem as a logistic regression by treating duration > 30 as a binary variable. If you haven't covered logistic regression yet, just model all the data and consider what values of (significant) predictors would lead to users taking trips of duration greater than 30 minutes.

With the model on the full data, you could also try backwards elimination to remove unneeded predictor variables. i.e. `step(dur, direction = "backward", trace=FALSE )`.

Additionally, your model R2 is very low. This suggests your model is no better than a mean model (i.e. almost all of the observed variation is not explained by variation in your predictors).

The model output doesn't show Sunday as this is the 'base' effect (or reference level) and all the other effects are relative to this. This is the default behaviour in R for regression with categorical predictors. The full answer for this is quite technical and can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032858/lm-summary-not-display-all-factor-levels

Edit: apparently there are various problems with backwards selection. Considering this is entry level modelling and didactic in nature, my view is that it's appropriate. If you have been taught different  variable selection techniques, feel free to use those.

Comment: I did a new column which says if the trip exceeds the time's limit, $1$ if i exceed, $0$ otherwise, but when I tried regression like this ```glm.fit <- glm(Exceed ~ Age + Origen_Id + Destiny_Id , data = df, family = binomial)```, my session in R was aborted :(, what I did worng?

Comment: Hi there, was there any error, warning, or message? It's difficult to say what the problem is without looking at the data.

Comment: no, it just say that R encountered a fatal error, I don'tk now if is because Origen_Id and Destiny_Id are in the data frame as charecter or because the two of them have many factor(there are like $230$ stations in total)

Comment: I recommend excluding those variables from your model. Yes, that could be the source of the error. Unless you have many observations or a specific reason to include them, that doesn't seem sensible to me.

'glm.fit <- glm(vs ~ disp , data = mtcars, family = binomial)' works fine for me; I assume it's a problem with either your data or environment. Try work from a fresh environment, running the command on toy data, a subset of your data, then the full data. Try cleaning your data (no NAs, NaNs or Infs), make sure the data types are compatible for glm command.

Comment: oh thanks!, do you think it would be okay just try to predict if the user could exceed the time based on the parameters: "age, gender" and maybe if is weekday or weekend?