# R lm difference between interactions with category and one models per category

Tags: r, interaction, lm

I am analysing a dataset of the performance of several species given an environmental variable.

To do so, I use a simple linear model with the lm function from the stats package.

**Model 1**

```r
formula_All_Species = Perf ~ -1 + Species + Species:Env + 
           Species:Env_sq
```

`Species` is a factor, `Env` is a numeric, as well as `Env_sq` with Env_sq = Env^2.

I look at the results for a single species (for instance, I look at the coefficients `Species01`, `Species01:Env` and `Species01:Env_sq`).

I wonder if this Model 1 is different from the following Model 2 inferred for each of the single species:

**Model 2**

```r
formula_Single_Species = 1 + Env + Env_sq
```

**In summary**, how is a model with interactions between categories and variables different from several models without interaction (one for each category)?

Comment: If you have categorical variable, the two models shouldn't be different.  If you choose 1 particular species and simplify Model 1 by removing all of the other species you should end up with Model 2.  I think your question is similar to this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547577/multiple-regression-r-output-how-to-interpret-the-intercept/547588#547588

Comment: Thank you, I was simply wondering if there was a difference in the inference of the parameters or something like this, I am happy to have a confirmation that both models are equivalent for a single species.