# What do the p-values for each variable in the output lm() in R mean?

Tags: r, anova, p-value, lm

I have a rudimentary understanding of statistics so please forgive me for my ignorance with technical terminology and potentially dumb questions.

I am trying to use the function lm() in R to determine whether my principal component scores obtained from a geometric morphometric analysis are being affected by my categorical variables such as genus and species.

I have been doing the function lm() to do this, which provides me with a linear regression and an ANOVA.

```
PC1 <- c(0.089414000, 0.068370913, -0.050999251, -0.04587411, -0.170857112, -0.155809758, -0.139814609)
PC2 <- c(-0.02134851, -0.045308158, 0.117697828, -0.011915008, 0.029505687, -0.009285337, -0.130873741)
Families <- c('Accipitridae','Accipitridae', 'Falconidae', 'Falconidae', 'Cariamidae', 'Cariamidae', 'Teratornithidae')
class.df <- data.frame(Families, PC1, PC2)

test <- lm(PC1 ~ Families, data = class.df)
summary(test)

Call:
lm(formula = PC1 ~ Families, data = class.df)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
 1.052e-02 -1.052e-02 -2.563e-03  2.563e-03 -7.524e-03  7.524e-03 -4.337e-19 

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              0.078892   0.007613   10.36 0.001917 ** 
FamiliesCariamidae      -0.242226   0.010766  -22.50 0.000192 ***
FamiliesFalconidae      -0.127329   0.010766  -11.83 0.001300 ** 
FamiliesTeratornithidae -0.218707   0.013186  -16.59 0.000477 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.01077 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9948,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9896 
F-statistic: 191.4 on 3 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.0006353
```

So my questions are:

1. Why does the output of this function show only three of the four families specified in my variables (in this case it skipped Accipitridae)?
2. What do the p-values listed next to each of the variables mean?
3. Is there a way to make all of my variables show up in this list with their own p-value/does it even matter?

Thank you in advance for any help and I am sorry if this has an obvious answer.

Comment: Another interpretation https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547577/multiple-regression-r-output-how-to-interpret-the-intercept/547588#547588

Answer (score 1):

1. The missing category has been lumped into the intercept.  When the other coefficients are 0, this leaves just the intercept which is interpreted as the Accipitridae category.
2. These are Wald tests for the coefficients.  They are tests of the null that the coefficient is equal to 0.
3. You could do `lm(PC1 ~ Families-1, data = class.df)`.  This removes the intercept from the model.  This will change the interpretation of the other coefficients and the p values probably won't be very useful anymore (because then you'd be testing the null that the group means are 0 rather than the difference in group means).  It won't change anything except the interpretation of the coefficients.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried to do the Families-1 but it returned the error "Error in Families - 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator". 

But if doing this is going to negate the usefulness of the p-values anyway, should I even bother doing it? Do I assume whatever p-value is given for the intercept is Accipitridae or should I just ignore those p-values and only use the F-statistic p-value to note that the category Families has an overall effect on PC1?

Comment: Use F stat, I would keep the intercept in the model generally speaking.