Interpreting coefficients from regression model especially intercept and choice of reference with categorical factor
I could use some help with interpretation of coefficients from a regression model. I've seen many similar questions here, but I haven't found one that helped answer some of these specific questions. My questions seem like they are agnostic to regression model choice, but for what it's worth this data is from a beta regression with a response variable of percentage (transformed to (0,1)). I'll use gender as a simple example of categorical factor with only two levels. I'm sure I'm phrasing some of this incorrectly, but bear with me...
If I select female as the reference, these are my coefficients and p-values:




Estimate
Std. Error
z value
Pr(>z)




(Intercept)
0.3276
0.1331
2.461
0.0139 *


GenderM
-0.3008
0.1927
-1.561
0.1186



The overall effect of Gender is p=0.12, with Male having no significant influence relative to the reference (Female). I think the intercept being significant suggests that Female has a significant effect relative to 0(?).
If I select Male as the reference:




Estimate
Std. Error
z value
Pr(>z)




(Intercept)
0.02685
0.13957
0.192
0.847


GenderF
0.30077
0.19272
-1.561
0.119



The overall effect of gender is the same, 0.12, and Female is now not significantly different compared to the reference (Male), same as before. I also understand how the coefficients in each scenario are related to each other mathematically. But the intercept is now not significant, suggesting that Male has no significant effect relative to 0.
How should I interpret these differences in the intercept with respect to choice of reference? it doesn't impact the overall interpretation of the significance of the Gender factor, but does it change how you interpret Female and Male individually?

Is it correct to interpret a significant intercept term as an effect of the reference level of the factor? In this case, when Female is the reference, being female has a significant positive effect on the response variable while male has a nonsignificant effect relative to female.
Depending on the answer to that first question, if I choose M as the reference, how would I know that F has some significant impact without testing all the different choices of reference? This is trivial for gender, but for a factor with more levels it could become more involved to evaluate all the reference options in the absence of a rationale choice of reference (e.g., a control).
OR - I suppose another possibility is that I shouldn't be paying attention to p values for individual coefficients if the factor itself is not significant?


Reviewing this question may help https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547577/multiple-regression-r-output-how-to-interpret-the-intercept/547588#547588

Re your first bullet: what would a "positive effect" possibly mean? A meaningful effect has to be in comparison with something else.  For instance, consider an observational study in which the heights of human adults are recorded and whether the subjects were wearing any red clothing is also noted.  The intercept in a regression of height vs. red/non-red will be significantly nonzero and positive, but in what way would that mean red clothing has a "significant positive effect on" height??

"Relative to 0" makes no sense here.  You can only compare levels of a categorical variable to other levels that actually exist. Also, note that the effects of male and female are NOT the same, they are opposite to each other (as is always the case with a two level variable). The p values are the same because men are just as different from women as women are different from men.

Thank you, these comments have each been helpful. The core I come back to is trying to understand how the intercept should be interpreted relative to the reference level of the factor. Or, what does a significant intercept say about the factor/variable itself (if anything)?
Here, it is suggested that the intercept represents the reference level for categorical factors:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70459515/is-there-a-way-to-display-the-reference-category-in-a-regression-output-in-r#:~:text=The%20reference%20level%20is%20the,mean%20in%20the%20reference%20category.

WIth some additional searching in the message boards here, I found another answer that helped me. I think I have a grasp on this now.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65082254/how-to-effectively-use-categorical-variables-in-a-regression
